# How do I find out where my app is leaking memory?

Tags: delphi

I am using following class

```
 mycalss = class

     public

        Self.timer1: TTimer;
        Self.abitmap: tbitmap;
        Self.animage: TImage;
        Self.formxyz:form;
     //some other declaration
     //also having my own constructor and destructor overridden

    end;
```

when a button is clicked myclass1 will be created and when other button is clicked myclass1 will be destroyed

```
 begin

    FreeAndNil(Self.timer1) ;
    FreeAndNil(Self.abitmap)    ;
    FreeAndNil(Self.animage);
      //others
    Self.formxyz.Close ;
    FreeAndNil(Self.formxyz);
    FreeAndNil(Self) ;

    inherited Destroy;
 end;
```

when ever i click on create button the windows task manager is showing 800 kb increase in memory consumption and whenever i click destroy there is only 500kb decrease ,

I am quite sure that the size increment is taking place when it is creating(not because of other side effects)as my app is a simple one.

**Question** :**Can I expect the delphi application to remove all the objects(~800kb) created to be removed on destroy operation(If i have done freeing properly)?.**

Comment: Actually if you destroy your object then you can call only Free() in Destroy procedure. You can use FreeAndNil() only when you need to re-assign variables.

Comment: `FreeAndNil(Self) ` that part is certainly wrong.

Comment: Also it's usually better to call `inherited destroy` in the end of your constructor.

Comment: Put "ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True" in .dpr file and check. It will display memory leaks if any

Comment: It would help if you posted your actual code. This is not it. Set `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` to `True` to get FastMM to report memory leaks to you. Install full FastMM if you want detailed reports. Don't rely on the figures quoted in Task Manager to diagnose memory leaks. Virtual memory is complex. Memory managers are complex. Step 1 is to get FastMM to help you. Finally, what was wrong with my answer to your previous question? If might not have solved your actual problem, but it is the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: If the second of code-snippets is the destructor of your class, the freeing of the class shoud raise an EStackOverflow-Exception, because you call FreeAndNil(Self). This will always call Destroy again, before it leaves the method.

Answer (score 1):

First only free object that you allocated in the class - do not destroy the self variable 
this will have some nice side effects when calling inherited and that inherited class also wants to free things.

The only reliable thing to check for memory leaks is to enable ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown or
even better - download the FastMM sources from sourceforge.

Second I think your encountering a speciality of the internal memory manager - the internal memory manager only frees memory of very large allocated blocks. Looking at the internals it reveals that the memory manager basically consists of 3 block managers, a small, a medium and
a manager for large blocks. For the small and medium blocks the manager keeps the memory and does not deallocate it to windows - the likelyhood that it will be reused in near future is quite high. It only immediately deallocates the memory for large blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor and destructor should look like this:

```
constructor TMyClass.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  timer1:= TTimer.Create;
  Bitmap1:= TBitmap.Create;
  AnImage:= TImage.Create(AOwner);
  ...
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  timer1.Free;
  abitmap.Free;
  animage.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

Because you are not reusing any members it makes no sense to call FreeAndNil.